# 'QueryDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, api, django-views

when i want run a code, create user in my blog, i get

> error 500

and

> 'QueryDict' object is not callable

and problem in this row  :

> data = form.data()

my code below:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostFormClass(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = form.data()
            dump = json.dumps(data)
            return JsonResponse(dump, content_type="application/json")
        return JsonResponse({"message": "invalid form"})
    else:
        form = PostFormClass()
        args = {'form': form}
        return JsonResponse(args, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: `form.data()` makes no sense, since `.data` is an attribute, that will give you back the `request.POST`. Nevertheless, you likely want to use `form.cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

`form.data` is an *attribute*, it will give you the data based on which you constructed the form, so in this case `request.POST`. Since `form.data` is an attribute, calling it wall make a call on the `QueryDict` object, which does not make much sense.

Nevertheless, you probably are *not* looking for the `form.data`, but the `form.cleaned_data`, this is the "product" of a `Form`. You thus can use:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostFormClass(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = form.data()
            dump = json.dumps(data)
            return JsonResponse(form.cleaned_data)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'invalid form'})
    else:
        form = PostFormClass()
        args = {'form': form}
        return JsonResponse(args, content_type="application/json")
```

Beware however that not everything *can* be JSON serialized, for example a model object, a `QuerySet`, etc. so depending on the fields you use in the form, JSON serializing it will produce an error.